# R version 4.0.1 does not analyse my data properly

Tags: r

I recently installed R version 4.0.1 (Nickname:See Things Now) on my new laptop and it isnt analysing my data properly. However the same codes with the same data analysed in version 3.6.1 (Nickname: Action of the Toes) on another laptop gives me the appropriate results. I would appreciate an explanation for this.

Example: "summary(CamelinaSeed$Type)" gives the output in version 4.0.1
Length     Class      Mode
37522 character character

With version 3.6.1: "summary(CamelinaSeed$Type)" : Camelina Microcarpa       Camelina Sativa   1050  36472

Comment: The big change between R ver 3 vs R ver 4 is the default behavior when creating dataframes.  In R ver 4 the behavior will convert strings into a character object while in previous versions the default is was to convert strings into factors.

Comment: How do i set it to convert strings into factors please? Cheers

Comment: In the data.frame function you could use `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` or convert the columns manually with the factor/as.factor functions

Comment: See [R now uses a stringsAsFactors = FALSE default](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html)

Comment: Thanks Dave, this worked.